# Writing List of Strings to Excel CSV File in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a csv file that contains the contents of a list of strings in Python, using the script below. However when I check my output file, it turns out that every character is delimited by a comma. How can I instruct `csv.writer` to delimit every individual string within the list rather than every character?

```
import csv

RESULTS = ['apple','cherry','orange','pineapple','strawberry']

result_file = open("output.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')
for item in RESULTS:
    wr.writerow(item)
```

I checked [PEP 305](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/#managing-different-dialects) and couldn't find anything specific.

Comment: I excel is the default dialect, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: I know you asked this question a long time ago, but I've got to know - if you're only putting a single item in each row, why do you need to use `csv`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#writer-objects) [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method takes an iterable as an argument. Your result set has to be a list (rows) of lists (columns).

> ```
> csvwriter.writerow(row)
> ```
>
> Write the *row* parameter to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current dialect.

Do either:

```
import csv
RESULTS = [
    ['apple','cherry','orange','pineapple','strawberry']
]
with open('output.csv','w') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(RESULTS)
```

or:

```
import csv
RESULT = ['apple','cherry','orange','pineapple','strawberry']
with open('output.csv','w') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow(RESULT)
```

Comment: Link to documentation: [csv module, Writer Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#writer-objects)

Comment: @Andrew: The second one works too, an if you need to write a single row, it is probably more appropriate (you may want to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue).

Comment: @crashmstr: Thanks, added the link inline too.

Comment: how can we manage the formats(date,string,number ...) when inserting into the excel file ?

Comment: @user1863359 unfortunately CSV files don't contain any formatting information.  Excel itself will make a guess on the appropriate format for each column.  Sometimes it guesses wrong: [Scientists rename human genes to stop Microsoft Excel from misreading them as dates](https://www.theverge.com/2020/8/6/21355674/human-genes-rename-microsoft-excel-misreading-dates).

Answer (score 37):

Very simple to fix, you just need to turn the parameter to [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) into a list.

```
for item in RESULTS:
    wr.writerow([item])
```

Answer (score 10):

I know I'm a little late, but something I found that works (and doesn't require using `csv`) is to write a for loop that writes to your file for every element in your list.

```
# Define Data
RESULTS = ['apple','cherry','orange','pineapple','strawberry']

# Open File
resultFyle = open("output.csv",'w')

# Write data to file
for r in RESULTS:
    resultFyle.write(r + "\n")
resultFyle.close()
```

I don't know if this solution is any better than the ones already offered, but it more closely reflects your original logic so I thought I'd share.

Comment: The main problem with writing csv files without using the `csv` module is that if your values contain quotes or commas, your file will be broken.

Answer (score 3):

A sample - write multiple rows with boolean column (using example above by GaretJax and Eran?).

```
import csv
RESULT = [['IsBerry','FruitName'],
          [False,'apple'],
          [True, 'cherry'],
          [False,'orange'],
          [False,'pineapple'],
          [True, 'strawberry']]
with open("../datasets/dashdb.csv", 'wb') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(RESULT)
```

Result:

```
df_data_4 = pd.read_csv('../datasets/dashdb.csv')
df_data_4.head()
```

Output:

```
   IsBerry  FruitName
   0    False   apple
   1    True    cherry
   2    False   orange
   3    False   pineapple
   4    True    strawberry
```