# Change characters inside a .txt file with script

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file:
`3.4 - New York, United States`

I need to create a script (preferably written in python) that can change the `-` (dash) character to a `,` (comma) character,

And then save the output as a .csv file

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: We're not going to write it for you.  I will recommend the `csv` module, and  make you aware of `str.replace('-', ',')`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh okay i'll try that.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh this is the error I get when I try to run it in a script I made:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "convert.py", line 11, in <module> str.replace('-', ',') TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: It looks like two arguments to me.  Can you edit the question with your script?  There's no way to get good formatting in comments

Comment: @PatrickHaugh OP literally ran `str.replace` (on the string class) not on some string instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSV module, here is a stackoverflow example, [Writing List of Strings to Excel CSV File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916542/writing-list-of-strings-to-excel-csv-file-in-python). If you want to replace the "-" with a "," open the file and read the string, replace it with `str.replace('-', ',')` and write it back to the file. Here is an example.

```
import csv
file = open("file_in.txt",'r')
file_out = open("file_out.csv",'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file_out)
writer.writerow(" ".join(file.read().replace('-', ','))) # added join method. 
file.close(); file_out.close()
```

Comment: This is the file_out.csv file I get:
`3,.,4, ,",", ,N,e,w, ,Y,o,r,k,",", ,U,n,i,t,e,d, ,S,t,a,t,e,s,"
"
`

Comment: Try now, I added a join method. This should fix the problem, although you might have to split the string by comma and do it by column. Did you look at the link on "Writing List of Strings to CSV in Python"?