# Write String and integer to CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a code whose outputs are mentioned below.

```
  print "Total Bits:%d"%totalbits
  print "Number of totalbits-zeros: %d." %totalbitszeros
  print "Number of totalbits-ones: %d." %totalbitsones
  print "Number of BRAM-Zeros: %d." %count0_bram
  print "Number of BRAM-ones: %d." %count1_bram
  print "Number of NON_BRAM-Zeros: %d." %count0_nonbram
  print "Number of NON_BRAM-Ones: %d." %count1_nonbram
  print "difference_zero_non_BRAM:%d."%difference_zero_non_BRAM
  print "difference_ones_non_BRAM:%d."%difference_ones_non_BRAM
```

I want to write these data to the .csv file for this: I make a array like: `data=[['Total Bits',totalbits]]`

and write this code to write data to the .csv file.

```
for row in data:
   for col in row:
    out.write('%d;'%col))

   out.write('\n')
  out.close()
```

But it gives me an error as first element in the column is a string, is there any way to write this data to the .csv file with or without converting into an array. The output in the .csv file looks like first column a description (string) and second the numbers (integers).

```
Total bits                       77826496
Total number of bits@0:          74653999
Total number of bits@1:          3172497
Total number of BRAM  bits@0:    17242039
Total number of BRAM  bits@1:    62089
Total number of non-BRAM  bits@0: 57411960
Total number of non-BRAM  bits@:  3110408
```

Comment: use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **format** function. Like this:

```
data = [['Total Bits', 100]]
with open('output.csv','w') as out:
    for row in data:
        for col in row:
            out.write('{0};'.format(col))
        out.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with csv module:

```
import csv
a = [['Total bits',77826496],['Total number of bits@0',74653999],['Total number of bits@1',3172497],\
     ['Total number of BRAM  bits@0',17242039],['Total number of BRAM  bits@1',62089],\
     ['Total number of non-BRAM  bits@0', 57411960],['Total number of non-BRAM  bits@',3110408]]
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=':')
    writer.writerows(a)
```

`output.csv` file will be:

```
Total bits:77826496
Total number of bits@0:74653999
Total number of bits@1:3172497
Total number of BRAM  bits@0:17242039
Total number of BRAM  bits@1:62089
Total number of non-BRAM  bits@0:57411960
Total number of non-BRAM  bits@:3110408
```