# Only the first and third element printed from python list to csv file

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I am trying write a list to a csv file.
I face several problems.

1. writer = csv.writer(f) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'writer'

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string) to solve it and it worked, and only printed the second for without writing the first and third for.

this is the code writen by [@gumboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7181046/gumboy)

```
csv = [['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['3', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]

csvdict = {words[0]:words[1:] for words in csv}
for x in csvdict.keys(): # iterate over the keys '1', '2', ....
    products = [index+1 for index,v in enumerate(csvdict[x]) if v == '1' ] # create list of purchases where the '1's are indexed

    print ("costummer", x, "buy", products)
```

The idea is to replace list that contains 1 with the list index. This problem is solved already. When I used the link above to solve the first problem, the code ran but did not write into the csv file.
I tried to combine the solution from the first problem with @gumboy code and here is the code:

```
csvdict = {words[0]:words[1:] for words in csv}
for x in csvdict.keys(): # iterate over the keys '1', '2', ....
    products = [index+1 for index,v in enumerate(csvdict[x]) if v == '1' ] # create list of purchases where the '1's are indexed

    #print (products)
    f = open("H.csv", 'w')
    hasil = ("costummer", x, "buy", products)
    hasilstr = (','.join([str(x) for x in hasil]))
    print (hasilstr)
    f.write(hasilstr)
```

Like I mentioned above, the code is working but only printed second for without print the first and third element.

**print function vs what is written on csv file:** 
print :

```
costummer,1,buy,[12, 22] 
costummer,2,buy,[8, 12, 38, 46]
costummer,3,buy,[4, 34, 43]
```

csf file :

```
costummer,2,buy,[8, 12, 38, 46]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with the `f = open('H.csv','w')` is that it is write to the file but also writing over your data. What you need to do is use `f =open('H.csv', 'a+')` this appends new string everytime to the file.[link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
To sort data use

```
for x in sorted(csvdict.keys()):
```

With this code I was able to write to file what was printed on console.

```
csvfile = [['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['3', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
csvdict = {words[0]:words[1:] for words in csvfile}
for x in sorted(csvdict.keys()): # iterate over the keys '1', '2', ....
    products = [index+1 for index,v in enumerate(csvdict[x]) if v == '1' ] # create list of purchases where the '1's are indexed

    #print (products)
    f = open("H.csv", 'a+')
    hasil = ("costummer", x, "buy", products)
    hasilstr = ("costummer, %s,buy,"+','.join([str(i) for i in products])) %(x)
    print (hasilstr)
    f.write(hasilstr +"\n")
```

Comment: yeah that's interesting, i did't notice is because they print second element and not the third element. so by converting the list into str is the right move sir ? the other things is  why it won't print the last (third for) element ?

Comment: What is your desire csv output?

Comment: CMIIW, they will write what they print right ? i mean i just wanna clarified what am i doing above is not abused the  looping logic. since print and write hasilstr, they should write what it print right ? i this case they print : costummer,1,buy,[12, 22],

costummer,2,buy,[8, 12, 38, 46],

costummer,3,buy,[4, 34, 43], but they only printed costumer 1 and 2.

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: there must be wrong with my pc becasue i copy you code 100% and it print 3 costumer and still just print 2 costumer in csv lol.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you open the file again for each iteration of the for loop (open it just once) and then overwrite it because you pass `'w'` as the 'mode' argument (if you just want to append something to the file you can pass 'a').

What you should actually do is, import the `csv` module, open the file with a `with` statement, create a writer `writer = csv.writer(csv_file)`, write the header and then the rows in the for loop. (Also, rename the `csv` list, because `csv` is the name of the module.)

```
import csv


lst = [...]  # Your csv list.
csvdict = {words[0]:words[1:] for words in lst}

with open('temp.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(('costumer', 'buy'))  # Write the header.
    for costumer in csvdict:
        products = [index for index, v in enumerate(csvdict[costumer], 1) if v == '1']
        writer.writerow((costumer, products))
```

The resulting csv file will look like this (the first column contains the costumers and the second the products):

```
costumer;buy
3;[4, 34, 43]
2;[8, 12, 38, 46]
1;[12, 22]
```

Comment: thank you sir, I am just curious can we remome the " " ?  i try to remove the list braked and the "" so far i used your code like this =         products1 = " ,".join(str(x) for x in products)
        writer.writerow((costumer, products1)) and it remove the list braked but still have know idea how to remove the ""

Comment: The csv writer had to add the quotes because commas were used as the delimiters and because a list also uses commas to separate the items. You can prevent this by passing a different delimiter like semicolon. I've edited the example.

Comment: muchas gracias sir.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, it seems that storing your data in a [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) file could be a better alternative.

Comment: thank you sir, next time i will try to used json file instead.